# meaning of push: function in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the meaning of return { push:function ..... in below code snippet. When I googled I found that push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns the new length. So I am not sure what is push:. It seems to be some kind of syntax. Can someone please explain me.

```js
function(notificationsArchive) {
  var MAX_LEN = 10;
  var notifications = [];
  return {
    push: function(notification) {
        var notificationToArchive;
        var newLen = notifications.unshift(notification);
        //push method can rely on the closure scope now!
        if (newLen > MAX_LEN) {
          notificationToArchive = this.notifications.pop();
          notificationsArchive.archive(notificationToArchive);
        }
      },
      // other methods of the NotificationsService
  };
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with push with Arrays, it is a public method exposed by the revealing module pattern.

Comment: and it's property name was arbitrarily chosen by author

Answer (score 1):

The method push you are referencing has nothing to do with push with Arrays, it is a *public* method exposed by the module pattern. It only exposes methods and properties that the author of the code wants you to be able to call/set. It hides the variables MAX_LEN and notifications so they can not be changed from outside.

References on OO Module patterns:

- http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript
- http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/05/13/JavaScript-Design-Patterns-The-Revealing-Module-Pattern